# CSS configurar posición de elemento dinámico

Tags: css, bootstrap, reactjs

Tengo un componente buscador en react, que una vez es submiteado, muestra una lista con los resultados.

```
 return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div className='input-group position-relative'>
    <Input type='text'
      placeholder='Buscar Paciente'
      name='input_search'
      onChange={handleChange}
      required={true}
      error={errors.input_search}
      value={values.input_search || ''}
    />
    <div className='input-group-append'>
      <button
        className='btn btn-outline-secondary position-absolute'
        type='submit' >
        <i className='fas fa-search'></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {
    loader ? <Loader /> :
      patients.length > 0 &&
      <RenderResults patients={patients} />
  }

</form>

);
```

> Por otro lado tengo el componente renderResults que es el encargado de renderizar los resultados de busqueda, y es donde tengo los problemas

```
return (
<div className='list-group'>
  {
    items.map(item =>
      <button key={item.pk}
        type="button"
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        {item.first_name}
      </button>
    )
  }

</div>
)
```

> Ahora, paso a mostrarles lo que se ve. Primero, el formulario de búsqueda vacío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Y una vez que le envio datos, veo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Ahora, las dos cosas que yo quisiera hacer son las siguientes:

1. Que el div Patients (que tiene un select con el valor DNI y un input) no se coloque abajo de los resultados de búsqueda, sino que se coloque atrás.
2. Quisiera poder hacer click en cualquier parte por fuera de los resultados de la busqueda, y que el elemento se deje de ver

Si pudieran ayudarme al menos con el punto 1, sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: El punto 1 lo resolvi posicionando el Form con relative, y el list-grop en absolute. Ahora me queda la duda de como hacer que se cierre cuando haga click en otro lado

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234988/8613688) tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo. Tienes que controlar el evento `click` para detectar cuándo se está pulsando el menú desplegable u cualquier otro elemento.